# Direct assignment of int array to pointer

Tags: c, pointers, initialization, scalar, braced-init-list

Was trying to brush up my C concepts and now it seems all jumbled up :( in pointers, of course

This way of assigning `arr` to `ptr` works since we say `arr[]` will decay to `*arr`

```
int arr[] = {1, 2, 3};
int *ptr = arr;    // Access arr with ptr
```

But directly assigning the array to `*ptr` doesn't work

```
int *ptr = {1, 2, 3};
printf("%d\n", ptr[0]); // Segmentation fault
```

My understanding is that `int arr[] = {}` has a special meaning where a contiguous chunk of stack space is allocated and is directly referred to by the name `arr`

Trying to do the same thing with `int *ptr = {}` is just confusing the compiler ??

Comment: your code doesnt even compile for me

Comment: with `int *ptr = {1, 2, 3};` you are not allocating an array.

Comment: @Neil. Yes, I saw these warnings, but it did compile though

Comment: "say arr[] will decay to *arr" --> more like "`arr` will decay to `&arr[0]`".

Comment: `int a[5], *p = a; a[1] = p[1] = *(a + 1) = *(p + 1)`, and arrays decay to pointers on the first level in functions. However, they are also different types, `sizeof a != sizeof p`.

Comment: Note that this is initialization, not assignment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`{1, 2, 3}` does not mean “an array”. In a declaration, it is a list of initial values for some object with multiple parts.

In `int arr[] = {1, 2, 3};`, `{1, 2, 3}` is a list of three values to use to initialize the array `arr`.

In `int *ptr = {1, 2, 3};`, `{1, 2, 3}` would be a list of three values to use to initialize the pointer `ptr`. But `ptr` does not have multiple parts. All it has is one value, a memory address. So `{1, 2, 3}` would provide `1` to initialize the address, which is a problem because `1` is an `int`, not an address, so the compiler should issue a diagnostic message for that. And there is nothing for `2` or `3` to initialize, so the compiler should issue a diagnostic message for that.

You can use a *compound literal* to create an unnamed array directly in source code. A compound literal has the form `(type) { initial values }`. So you can create an array of `int` with `(int []) {1, 2, 3}`.

You can declare a pointer and initialize it to point to an array by using a compound literal as the initial value:

```
int *ptr = (int []) {1, 2, 3};
```

(Note that the array is automatically converted to a pointer to its first element, so `ptr` is initialized to that address.)

Comment: Thanks for clarifying this. Going by the same logic, initialize an object with multiple parts, shouldn't this work `int (*arr)[3] = {1, 2, 3}` ? Pointer to an array of five numbers and accessing it as `(*arr)[i]`. This also works only with `(int [])`

Comment: @mittal: No. `int (*arr)[3]` declares `arr` to be a pointer to an array of three `int`. A pointer has only one part, an address. The fact it points to something with multiple parts is irrelevant.

Comment: Oh ok. I guess I am not able to understand what exactly is `arr[]` that has multiple parts. I understood that `*ptr` has only 1 part

Comment: @mittal: Each element of an array is part of the array.

Comment: Oh, so you mean `pointer` is `scalar` type so it can't accept more than 1 value. But `array` is `aggregate` type and would accept multiple parts. Correct ?

Comment: @mittal: Yes, pointers are scalars, and scalars have just one value, and arrays are aggregates, and aggregates have one or more members or elements.

Comment: I came across this link too https://www.cs.fsu.edu/~myers/cgs3408/notes/arrays2.html, that says `An array is a primitive C-style construct that consists of many items stored consecutively and accessed through a single variable name (and indexing)`. I believe that clears my doubt

Comment: @mittal: Do not use that source. It is wrong on several points. “An array is not a type” is not correct, except with a strained interpretation. An array is a type, at least when completed with details such as “an array of 3 `int`”. Even “an array of `int`” is a type in C semantics, albeit incomplete. And “The name of an array acts as special kind of variable -- a pointer…” is incorrect. It is often converted to a pointer, but considering it to be a pointer will lead to mistakes.

Answer (score 4):

The variable `ptr` is a scalar object. You may initialize a scalar object with a braced list that contains only one expression.

From the C Standard (6.7.9 Initialization)

> 11 **The initializer for a scalar shall be a single expression,
> optionally enclosed in braces.** The initial value of the object is
> that of the expression (after conversion); the same type constraints
> and conversions as for simple assignment apply, taking the type of the
> scalar to be the unqualified version of its declared type.

So instead of:

```
int *ptr = {1, 2, 3};
```

you may write for example:

```
int *ptr = { 3 };
```

that is equivalent to:

```
int *ptr = 3;
```

and does not make a sense and the compiler can issue a message that an integer is converted to a pointer without casting.

Instead of the braced list you could initialize the pointer with a compound literal like:

```
int *ptr = ( int [] ){1, 2, 3};
```

In this declaration there is created an unnamed array of the type `int[3]` and the address of the first element of the array is assigned to the pointer.